# Spring: formatting a date in a REST response without modifying the domain class

Tags: spring, date, jackson

I have a Spring 5 (not spring boot) project that has an endpoint returning an object that is defined in a dependency jar (I cannot modify it). This object has a field that is a date (LocalDateTime).

The date is formatted as this in the response:

```
{
    "dayOfMonth": 21,
    "dayOfWeek": "THURSDAY",
    "month": "FEBRUARY",
    "year": 2019,
    "dayOfYear": 52,
    "hour": 11,
    "minute": 24,
    "nano": 753000000,
    "second": 32,
    "monthValue": 2,
    "chronology": {
        "id": "ISO",
        "calendarType": "iso8601"
    }
}
```

How can I write is as ISO 8601 or similar? I tried adding the following dependencies:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-datatype-jsr310</artifactId>
    <version>2.9.8</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-datatype-jdk8</artifactId>
    <version>2.9.8</version>
</dependency>
```

I also tried to create a primary bean for the ObjectMapper:

```
@Bean
@Primary
public ObjectMapper objectMapper() {
    ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
    objectMapper.registerModule(new JavaTimeModule());
    objectMapper.registerModule(new Jdk8Module());
    objectMapper.disable(SerializationFeature.WRITE_DATES_AS_TIMESTAMPS);
    return objectMapper;
}
```

The mapper works fine when used explicitly but not when Spring returns a JSON REST response.

To simplify and not writing the whole code, I would like for endpoints such as the one below to implicitly format the date correctly.

```
    @GetMapping(path = "/date", produces = "application/json")
    public @ResponseBody ResponseEntity<LocalDateTime> date(@RequestHeader HttpHeaders headers) {
        return new ResponseEntity<>(LocalDateTime.now(), HttpStatus.OK);
    }
```

Thank you.

Comment: Your `ObjectMapper` seems to be fine, including the module registration. Are you sure that's the `ObjectMapper` instance that's actually used to serialize the response payload?

Comment: I am not sure, but I don't really know how to check this. Do I need to register the ObjectMapper as the default object mapper for Jackson ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it by adding a Configuration class that links my ObjectMapper to the HTTPMessageConverter based on this [blog entry](http://magicmonster.com/kb/prg/java/spring/webmvc/jackson_custom.html#anchor2).

```
@Configuration
public class JacksonConfiguration {

    @Autowired
    ObjectMapper mapper;

    private RequestMappingHandlerAdapter annotationMethodHandlerAdapter;

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        List<HttpMessageConverter<?>> messageConverters = annotationMethodHandlerAdapter.getMessageConverters();
        for (HttpMessageConverter<?> messageConverter : messageConverters) {
            if (messageConverter instanceof MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter) {
                MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter m = (MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter) messageConverter;
                m.setObjectMapper(mapper);
            }
        }
    }

    @Autowired
    public void setAnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter annotationMethodHandlerAdapter) {
        this.annotationMethodHandlerAdapter  = annotationMethodHandlerAdapter;
    }
}
```